# PostSharp compile error

Tags: c#, postsharp

I've followed the examples that come with postsharp 1.5 .. And I've a two simple projects:

One has an aspect like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyAspectAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Method.Name);
        base.OnEntry(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

In the other project I've a test case like this:

```
public class Test
{
    [MyAspect]
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.Write("aa");
    }
}
```

In the same project of "test", I've the following test fixture:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void TestDoSomething()
    {
        var a = new Test();
        a.DoSomething();
    }}
```

The code won't compile because a postsharp exception:

```
Error   2   Unhandled exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'PostSharp.CodeModel.TypeDefDeclaration' to type 'PostSharp.CodeModel.IMethod'.
   at PostSharp.Laos.Weaver.MethodLevelAspectWeaver.get_TargetMethod()
   at PostSharp.Laos.Weaver.MethodLevelAspectWeaver.Initialize()
   at PostSharp.Laos.Weaver.OnMethodBoundaryAspectWeaver.Initialize()
   at PostSharp.Laos.Weaver.LaosTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Extensibility.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Extensibility.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)
   at PostSharp.MSBuild.PostSharpRemoteTask.Execute(PostSharpTaskParameters parameters, TaskLoggingHelper log)  MyExample.Tests
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as a bug, but I wonder how your sample can cause this bug.
Did you try with the latest build or just the RTM?

If the bug is not solved, can you send a repro (a self-contained command-line project) to support@sharpcrafters.com?

Comment: I was with the RTM, I don't know.. I've started over with a new solution from scratch and it work like a charm. I'll see if I can make a repro.
Thank you